# Why is my date value parsed incorrectly in web api function?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2

I send from client to web api function this string:

```
date = "Sat, 27 Oct 2012 18:10:00 GMT"
```

This web api function get the string  and parse it:

```
    public HttpResponseMessage Get(DateTime date)
    {
        //some logic
    }
```

In debugging mode in web api function I check the value after it parsed I see this:

{10/27/2012 8:10:00 PM}

The result that I was seposed to get is:

{10/27/2012 18:10:00 PM}

Any idea why it parsed wrong?

Comment: How are you parsing it? Is it saving it in the local timezone time and not UTC?

Comment: You might want to post some codes to get answers.

Comment: The Parsing accures automatically in this row!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has to do with UTC time being sent and the date transformed to local time. To avoid this and other errors you should not be sending datetimes from your client in any other format that [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). This ensures your client code can be reused in any locale. This is especially true when it comes to browsers and websites you have little control over locales users have installed. If they have the browser installed in Spanish `es-MX` the format of the date could be day then month then year which would not be parsed correctly if sent as as a normal date time.

`ISO8601` also preserves the time offset when it is sent to the server.

When sending the date from JavaScript the datetime object contains a method called [.toISOString()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_toisostring.asp). Call this when creating your string to send to the server.

On the web server you can then use either DateTime which will then have the .Kind = Utc or you can use `DateTimeOffset`. Either way the date/time will be materialized correctly if you send it as a ISO8601 compliant string.

This has also been [answered before here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36066269/1260204).

#### Recap

- Always use `ISO-8601` from and to the client (*to client is usually handled automatically by the JSON formatter in Web API*).
- Always use `DateTimeOffset` or `DateTime` instances directly in your model.

Comment: Here is sigment code from client before I send it to server:

var date = new Date(Date.parse(sensorsData[0].MeasureDate)).toISOString();

Comment: As you can see I use ISO. But still in web api it not parsed

Comment: `var dataToSendToServer = date.toISOString();`

Comment: `date = "Sat, 27 Oct 2012 18:10:00 GMT"` - this is **not** ISO format. ISO 8601 would be `2012-10-27T18:10:00Z`

Comment: See the link provided to the Wiki about ISO8601.

Comment: Before that: date = "Sat, 27 Oct 2012 18:10:00 GMT" I tryed that:
"2012-10-27T18:10:00.000Z"

Comment: That is the correct format. If you then check the materialized DateTime object in your method it will have the `date.Kind` equal to `DateTimeKind.Utc`. This is what you would want.

Answer (score 1):

`Sat, 27 Oct 2012 18:10:00 GMT` date is formatted in *Coordinated Universal Time (UTC)*.

The value you are receiving in `date` variable is the same but is using your local time zone.

You can get the universal time from `date` using `ToUniversalTime()` method:

```
date.ToUniversalTime()
```

Comment: is it possible to get UniversalTime in web api signature method?

Comment: @Michael: Let me see, just a moment.